# PushDownPredicate in Spark SQL and Exchange reuse

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am executing the given query containing a `UNION`. My intention is to reuse the exchange between both the query branches by disabling `PushDownPredicate` configuration setting in the Spark-shell.

With `PushDownPredicate` **enabled**, Spark will push down the filter condition close to the source and hence insert `1` Exchange (Shuffle) on each branch of the queries - resulting in total `2` Exchanges.

However, the expectation is that - with the `PushDownPredicate` **disabled**, Spark will not push the filter close to the source by holding the filter condition at its original place in the query - i.e. after the `group by`  clause. This will let Spark use only a **single** Exchange (for both the queries) thereby reducing 1 shuffle.

Unfortunately I am not being able to produce this action with Spark SQL. The query and the commands are given below:

Configuration:

```
spark-sql> SET "spark.sql.optimizer.excludeRules", org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.PushDownPredicate;
```

Query:

```
select prodId, count(*) as cnt
from test_db.product
group by 1
having count(*) > 1000
and prodId = '1234'
union all
select prodId, count(*) as cnt
from test_db.product
group by 1
having count(*) < 100;
```

Physical Plan:

```
Union
:- *(2) Project [prodId#5539, count(1)#5576L]
:  +- *(2) Filter (count(1)#5579L > 1000)
:     +- *(2) HashAggregate(keys=[prodId#5539], functions=[count(1)])
:        +- Exchange hashpartitioning(prodId#5539, 200)
:           +- *(1) HashAggregate(keys=[prodId#5539], functions=[partial_count(1)])
:              +- *(1) Project[prodId#5539]
:                 +- *(1) Filter (isnotnull(prodId#5539) && (prodId#5539 = 1234))
:                    +- *(1) FileScan parquet testdb.product[prodId#5539,eff_dt#5546] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: CatalogFileIndex[s3://path], PartitionCount: 1, PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(prodId), EqualTo(ProdId, 1234)], ReadSchema: struct<prodId:string>
+- *(4) Project[prodId#5568, count(1)#5577L]
   +- *(4) Filter (count(1)#5581L < 100)
      +- *(4) HashAggregate(keys=[prodId#5568], functions=[count(1)])
         +- Exchange hashpartitioning(prodId#5568, 200)
           +- *(3) HashAggregate(keys=[prodId#5568], functions=[partial_count(1)])
              +- *(3) Project [prodId#5568]
                 +- *(3) FileScan parquet testdb.product[prodId#5568,eff_dt#5575] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: CatalogFileIndex[s3://path], PartitionCount: 1, PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<prodId:string>
```

As seen from the above Query Plan, Spark is using `2` Exchanges -> `1` on each query branch. My intention is to reduce the 2 Exchanges into 1 **shared** Exchange, by using the configuration setting mentioned above.

I am using Spark v2.4.0.

Can anyone please help as to where I may be going wrong. Am I setting the configuration properly ?
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this :

`SET spark.sql.optimizer.excludedRules=org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.PushDownPredicate`